# ImportError: cannot import name '_ClassNamePrefixFeaturesOutMixin' from 'sklearn.base'

Tags: python, recursion, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, scikits

I am struggling to import **RFECV** from sklearn.feature_selection. But I always have the same error.
Can anyone help, please?
The error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_ClassNamePrefixFeaturesOutMixin' from 'sklearn.base' (C:\Users\sedam\anaconda34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py)
```

PS. The version of my SKlearn is 1.0.2.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there might be an issue with the python version you're using or a compatibility error with other packages.

For Windows, I'm afraid this might or mightn't work don't know haven't used it.

1. If you're on Python 3.10.* try with 3.9.*:

```
conda install python=3.9 -y ;
conda update conda -y && conda update python -y
```

2. Or else you can make a new env named sklearn or whatever:
   I'm creating mine with meow

```
conda create --name meow python=3.9 -y ;
conda activate meow ;
conda install python=3.9 -y ;
conda install numpy pandas matplotlib seaborn scikit-learn ipykernel -y
```

3. Or just simple Update conda and python if you are on 3.9.*:

```
conda update conda -y && conda update python -y
```

Answer (score 1):

solution : #conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn

Comment: conda ya indirmeniz lazım library yi

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).